# How to avoid the cyclic dependency in the cross-account s3 replication configuration

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm trying to configure cross-account s3 data replication, but CloudFormation service makes it difficult with its validations.

stack 1 contains the following construct:

```js
export default class CrossAccountReplicatedOriginBucket extends ManagedBucket {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: CrossAccountReplicatedOriginBucketProps) {
        super(scope, id, {
            ...props,
            versioned: true,
            lifecycleRules: [
                {
                    expiration: Duration.days(30),
                },
            ],
        });

        const replicationRole = new Role(this, "ReplicationRole", {
            roleName: props.replicationRoleName,
            assumedBy: new CompositePrincipal(
                new ServicePrincipal("s3.amazonaws.com"),

                // will be used for S3 batch operations for the disaster recovery
                new ServicePrincipal("batchoperations.s3.amazonaws.com"),
            ),
            inlinePolicies: {
                CrossAccountS3Access: new PolicyDocument({
                    statements: [
                        new PolicyStatement({
                            sid: "SourceBucketPermissions",
                            effect: Effect.ALLOW,
                            actions: [
                                "s3:InitiateReplication",
                                "s3:PutInventoryConfiguration",
                                "s3:GetObjectRetention",
                                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                                "s3:ListBucket",
                                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                                "s3:GetObjectLegalHold",
                                "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
                            ],
                            resources: ["*"],
                        }),
                        new PolicyStatement({
                            sid: "DestinationBucketPermissions",
                            effect: Effect.ALLOW,
                            actions: crossAccountS3ReplicationDestinationActions,
                            resources: [
                                props.replicationDestination.bucket.bucketArn,
                                `${props.replicationDestination.bucket.bucketArn}/*`,
                            ],
                        }),
                    ],
                }),
            },
        });

        if (props.enableReplication) {
            (this.node.defaultChild as CfnBucket).replicationConfiguration = {
                role: replicationRole.roleArn,
                rules: [
                    {
                        status: "Enabled",
                        priority: 1,
                        deleteMarkerReplication: {
                            status: props.replicateDeletions ? "Enabled" : "Disabled",
                        },
                        filter: {
                            prefix: props.replicationKeyFilter,
                        },
                        destination: {
                            bucket: props.replicationDestination.bucket.bucketArn,
                            account: props.replicationDestination.account,
                            accessControlTranslation: { owner: "Destination" },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            };
        }
    }
}
```

stack 2 contains the following definition:

```js
export default class CrossAccountReplicatedDestinationBucket extends SecureBucket {
    constructor(
        scope: Construct,
        id: string,
        props: Omit<SecureBucketProps, "usesCrossRegionReplication"> & {
            originAccountReplicationRole: IRole | IRole[];
        },
    ) {
        super(scope, id, {
            ...props,
            versioned: true,
        });

        this.addToResourcePolicy(
            new PolicyStatement({
                sid: "ReplicationPermissions",
                effect: Effect.ALLOW,
                principals: Array.isArray(props.originAccountReplicationRole)
                    ? props.originAccountReplicationRole
                    : [props.originAccountReplicationRole],
                actions: crossAccountS3ReplicationDestinationActions,
                resources: [this.bucketArn, `${this.bucketArn}/*`],
            }),
        );
    }
}
```

(the `ManagedBucket` and `SecureBucket` in this case are just sub-classes of CDK's `s3.Bucket` that add additional properties to the constructor that are not really relevant for this use case)

the issue is that CloudFormation apparently executes cross-account validation to make sure that my `replicationConfiguration` points to the bucket that actually exists.
Similarly, when deploying the destination bucket CloudFormation validates that the role I'm defining on stack 1 actually exists.

So the only way to deploy this right now is to make sure `props.enableReplication` is false, deploy stack 1, deploy stack 2, make sure `props.enableReplication` is true and deploy stack 1 again o_o
This feel wrong on so many levels.
What is the right way to handle this so that each stack needs to be deployed only once?